# How to send discord webhook message in Java?

Tags: java, url, discord, webhooks

I'm trying to send a discord webhook message from Java.
I found a way in this [website.](https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post)
But when i tried, it didn't work.

```java
package com.company;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Discord {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/my_webhook_url");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        String jsonInputString = "{" +
                "username : \"Bot\", " +
                "content : \"Hello World\"" +
                "}";
        try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm just using this for a one way message so, i guess this should work.
But why doesn't it?

Comment: Use a webhook library like this https://github.com/MinnDevelopment/discord-webhooks

Answer (score 1):

add
con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");